# ASP.net The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the following error:

```
  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

trying to save a file and then reading it, please can you help me to fix the code ?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
    string path = "\\\\nasouts01\\CodiceDiRete\\temp\\";



    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileExt = 
           System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

        if (fileExt == ".csv")
        {
            try
            {

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + FileUpload1.FileName);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Flush();
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Close();
                FileUpload1.FileContent.Dispose();    
                //Release File from Memory after uploading
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Selezionare soltanto file .csv";
            gwreportpub.Visible = false;
            ButtonConferma.Visible = false;
            ButtonAnnulla.Visible = false;
            ButtonPulisci.Visible = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Inserire un file ";
        gwreportpub.Visible = false;
        ButtonConferma.Visible = false;
        ButtonAnnulla.Visible = false;
        ButtonPulisci.Visible = false;
        return;
    }
    /*
    Validazione nel file , dopo visualizzazione dei dati nella tabella 
    */
    int count  = 0;
    string line;

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = 
    new System.IO.StreamReader(path+FileUpload1.FileName))
    {
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       count = line.Split(',').Length;
       if(count != 12){

         Label1.Text = "Il file non contiene il numero esatto di campi che servono al caricamento";
         gwreportpub.Visible = false;
         ButtonConferma.Visible = false;
         ButtonAnnulla.Visible = false;
         ButtonPulisci.Visible = false;
         return;

       }
    }

    file.Close();
    }
    /*
    Prendo il valore della sequence
    */
    OracleCommand sequenceCmd = new OracleCommand("select ls_seq_batchrequest.nextval from dual",connection);
    OracleDataReader reader = sequenceCmd.ExecuteReader();
    int sequenceVal=0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(0)));
        sequenceVal = reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
    reader.Close();

    Session["sequenceVal"] = sequenceVal;

    /*
    Faccio l'inserimento a db dei dati e visualizzo la tabella
    */
    OracleTransaction myTrans = null;


    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO ZTMP_SAM_TB_ELAB_PDR(facilityid,taxid,plantcode,ca_pdr, fullmeterkey_m1, corrmeterid_m1, " + 
    "stopreading_m1, corrstopreading_m1,fullmeterkey_m2, corrmeterid_m2, " + 
    "stopreading_m2, corrstopreading_m2, stopreadtime_m1,stopreadtime_m2,uidbatchrequest) " + 
    "  VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15)", connection);
    //myTrans = connection.BeginTransaction();
    //cmd.Transaction = myTrans; 
    /*
    ( :facilityid,:taxid,
    :plantcode,:capdr,:fullmetkeym2,
    :corrmetidm2,:stopreadingm2,
    :corrstopreadm2,:fullmetkeym1,
    :corrmetidm1,:stopreadingm1,:corrstopreadm1,
    :stopreadtimem2,:stopreadtimem1)
    */
    using (System.IO.StreamReader file2 = 
    new System.IO.StreamReader(path+FileUpload1.FileName))
    {
    //System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path+FileUpload1.FileName);
    try
    {
    while((line = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       string[] split = line.Split(',');


       cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[0];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = "";
       cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = "";
       cmd.Parameters.Add("4", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("5", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[6];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("6", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[7];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("7", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[8]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("8", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[9]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("9", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = split[2];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("10", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = split[3];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("11", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[4]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("12", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[5]);
       DateTime date1,date2;

       DateTime.TryParseExact(split[10], "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date1);
       DateTime.TryParseExact(split[11], "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date2);

       cmd.Parameters.Add("13", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date1;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("14", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date2;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("15", OracleType.Number).Value = sequenceVal;

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


       /*Per ogni elemento esegui l'insert*/
    }
    //myTrans.Commit();
    }   
    catch(Exception ex){

      //myTrans.Rollback(); 
      Label1.Text = ex.Message;
      return;
    //"Si e' verificato un errore nell'inserimento dei dati nella tabella ZTMP_SAM_TB_ELAB_PDR";
    }


    file2.Close();
    }


  }
```

Comment: that is large method i would suggest you break the process up into a number of smaller methods, it will be easier to debug from there

Comment: just a tip unrelated to your current issue: use string literals in c# to eliminate the need to escape your paths. E.g.: `string path = @"\\nasouts01\CodiceDiRete\temp\";` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Do you have try to change your path save as at local disk more than save to network sharing path? So far, it work well at my side when I try save it to local disk. I suspect your issue depends on your environment.

Comment: You can use the tool below to check which application locking your file: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx or http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/

Comment: @ToanVo yes you are right depens on the environment ... locally seems to not happen what can i do ??

Comment: From my view point, you need to check the file server where you upload file. It should turn off any scanning process (virus, cleaner program)  to make sure there is no other process access your file. Or you should upload to temporary locally drive to make sure this issue does not occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things to solve this

1. Save file with timestamp in name and work on that copy
2. Use `File.ReadLine` method if file is CSV.

Comment: what means Use File.ReadLine method if you it is CSV file. ??