# I'm trying to save an image to a folder in asp.net project but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The page refreshers and doesn't stop, and when I exit and check images folder, I find it empty. Plus if I click the upload button multiple times, I get the error

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Setup Game\source\uploads\Kleki.png' because it is being used by another process

How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
{
    string s = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads/" + s));
    Label25.Text = "image saved";
}
```

I also tried this code :

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/uploads/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.net The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611652/asp-net-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-p)

Comment: Did you try with _.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("uploads"), s));_ ?

Comment: Have you tried to place a tilde ~ in front of the mapped path? Like so: FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + s));

Comment: i retried this code SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("uploads"), s)) and it worked now thank you so much Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Glad that you have cleared the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341000/im-trying-to-save-an-image-to-a-folder-in-asp-net-project-but-it-doesnt-work).
- Based on your comments posting that as an answer to help the other `community members` who are facing with the same issue.
- Thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) for the valuable comment.
- Here is the correct `syntax` which we need to use to save an image to a folder in asp.net project.

```cs
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("uploads"), s));
```